# Is there mongodb query which will insert document if field is unique otherwise execute custom function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Trying to create an activation code which should be unique, but it only consists of specific characters.
So, this is solution which i build

```
function findByActivationId() {
   return Activation
        .findOne({activationId})
        .lean()
        .exec();
}
let activationId = buildActivationId();
while (await findByActivationId(activationId)) {
    activationId = buildActivationId();
}
```

This makes too many db calls, is there any better way to make query to mongodb?

Comment: You mean, you are generating an id, checking in the DB if it exists, if it does you generate another id, and check again if it exists, until it doesn't? Why not use a unique `activationId` index in Mongo, or generate a id you already know is unique to start with (using timestamp or something) ?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly i want to do. Id we are generating is consists of specific characters, so we use random function to generate string. Using unique index doesn't solve problem. It will throw an error. We still need to loop through to get unique activationId.

Comment: Index will guarantee uniqueness. With `find` there is a room for race condition when concurrent requests generate the same code. You will still need 1 insert call per attempt.

Comment: Yes, will add unique index to activationId, but my question is still if there is better solution such as make a mapreduce call. Is it efficient?

Comment: mapreduce is slow and it only queries data. It's intended for advanced ETL usecases. With unique index your inserts will take few milliseconds per attempt.

Comment: `Using unique index doesn't solve problem. It will throw an error.` --> Why would it throw an error, and if it did, which error? Unique indexes's job is exactly to do what you want to do. How do you know it wouldn't solve your problem?

Comment: @JeremyThille unique index throws an error on insert if you attempt to insert a document that violates the uniqueness constraint. It doesn't solve the problem because OP's problem is too many calls to the db. Employing a unique index will still require 1 insert call to the db per attempt. IMHO it's the way to go but it seems OP is looking for a better way

Answer (score 1):

Well, the major problem of checking if key is unique is based on how you are creating those.

Choose the best way for you to avoid bunch of problems later.

#### Your own generated string as a key

> Well, you can do this but it's important to understand few disclaimers
> If you want to generate your own key by the code and then compare if it is unique
> in the database with all other currently created it can be done. Just create key by your
> algorithm then select all keys from db and check if array of selected rows contains this freshly created string

**Problems of this solution**
As we can see we need to select all keys from DB and then compare each one to freshly created one. Problem can appear when your database is storing big amount of data. Every time application have to "download" big amount of data and then compare it to new one so in addition this might produce some freezes.

But if you are sure that your database will store not that much amount of unique rows, it is cool to work with.
Then it is important to create those keys properly. Now we talking about complexity, more symbols key is created from, harder to get same ones.

**Shall we take a look at this example?**

If you are creating keys based on letters a-z and numbers 1-9
and the length of key is for example 5, the complexity of this key is 35^5
which generates more than 52 milions possibilities.
Same keys can be generated but it is like a win on a lottery, almost impossible
*And then you can just check if generated key is really unique, if not. (oh cmon) Repeat.*

#### Other ways

> 1. Use mongodb _id which is always unique
> 2. Use UNIX timestamp to create unique key